# Solve the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\cos^{2}x}\cos\left\{ \left(2n+1\right)x\right\} dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**Question** For any integer $n$, solve the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\cos^{2}x}\cos\left\{ \left(2n+1\right)x\right\}\, dx$

**My Approach** I don't know how to approach .Please give me Hints

Comment: what does $$\{...}\$$ mean?

Comment: I'd try expanding out $\exp(\cos^2x)$ by the exponential series and then integrate termwise.

Comment: Zero by symmetry. $$\cos((2n+1)(\pi-x))=-\cos((2n+1)x)$$ while $$\cos^2(\pi-x)=\cos^2(x).$$

Comment: @Dr.Sonnhard Sir i don't know why are you having trouble in reading question.I wrote the question using LYX and i can read it clearly on my side.

Comment: Thanks for the hints .now i am gonna try it at my self

Comment: Thanks for the hint.Indeed it was very easy question with difficult looking settings